# Naming convention when converting between types?

Tags: c#, converting

If I have a method where the input is a list of integers, and within that method I convert the list to a list of strings, what is the best way to name the new list?

For example (using `C#`):

```
public void DoSomething(IEnumerable<int> cheeseburgerToppingIds)
{
    var cheeseburgerToppingIdsAsStrings = cheeseburgerToppingIds
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(p => p)
        .ToList()
        .ConvertAll(p => p.ToString());

    // do some other stuff
}
```

In this example, `cheeseburgerToppingIdsAsStrings` is descriptive, but also kind of clunky.

Comment: `var ids = ` and keep you method short, so it makes sense :)

Comment: The code presented looks generic/hypothetical. Please replace it with actual code from a project where you encountered the problem.

Comment: @greybeard -- so, I see your point, but it is mostly hypothetical. But I'm not sure where to post this question. It will also get closed at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ because it's opinion-based. But I _want_ opinions!

Comment: Well, *hypothetical* is [explicitly off-topic here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: (As an aside, this is one of the situations where I value languages with "duck typing". And all is lost where tradition mandates encoding parts of types in names as in `IEnumerable`.)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the context is really important, so I'm not sure your example is capturing it.  If the critical difference between two variables is the type, and especially if they're both being used around each other, adding the type to the name is fine.  If the issue that the ReallyLongName is obscuring the AsString suffix, I'd probably look for ways to extract the code into a simpler context where the long names aren't necessary.  Like, maybe do the conversion to strings ahead of time and have this method take an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. I see this as a decent answer to a question asked in an [off topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) way: [off-topic questions should not be answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). (It fails ***Is it actual code from a project** rather than pseudo-code or hypothetical code?*, and is one of the [types of questions to avoid asking: **Best practices in general**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).)